# How to fix Win UI C# application has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409)

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have two issues, I am trying to do the WIN UI tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app) for creating my first WINUI 3 application.  I follow all of the steps but get the error "application has exited with code -1073740791 (0xc0000409)."   I have added the WindowPackageType as none to the csproj file and still I get nothing.

```
 The other issue I am having is  that the SDK is showing yellow triangles, how to go about correcting that?
```

[SDK showing yellow triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhEy.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Bill O.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error problem. Can you make sure you followed the [Install tools for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=vs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b) corresponding to your VS2020 version (before 17.1 and later) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select x64 build configuration
2. Add these properties to your project

```
      <PropertyGroup>
       <WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.19041.18</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>
        <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

3. Make sure your VS isn't started elevated.
4. Upgrade to Windows App SDK 1.1 pre2.
5. Optional you can add these properties as well for troubleshooting purposes

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_Default>true</WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_Default>
    <WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnNoMatch_ShowUI>true</WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnNoMatch_ShowUI>
    <WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnError_DebugBreak>true</WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnError_DebugBreak>
    <WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnError_DebugBreak_IfDebuggerAttached>true</WindowsAppSDKBootstrapAutoInitializeOptions_OnError_DebugBreak_IfDebuggerAttached>
  </PropertyGroup>
```